# Why would totals.visits be NULL on a row where totals.newVisits is 1

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

I'm running a query to pull source, medium, some custom dimensions, new sessions (totals.newVisits), sessions (totals.visits) and session duration (totals.timeOnSite).

I get some results where there is a value for totals.newVisits, but not totals.visits. How would that be possible - isn't a new visit supposed to be a subset of all visits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to see these 2 variables ("totals.visits" and "totals.newVisits") **as indicators (booleans)**.

Here, we want to know whether the user have already gone to the website before the visit or he is a returning visitor (totals.newVisits) and whether the user have done an interaction during the session or not (totals.visits).

In that case, it's 2 independent variables.

That is why Google specify these variables like :

> The value is null if there are no interaction events in the session.

or

> If this is the first visit, this value is 1, otherwise it is null.

You have to really stick into Google's variables definitions : [BigQuery variable dictionary](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719)

Comment: Are you saying that newVisits isn't really a session indicator, but rather a new/returning indicator? That actually makes a lot of sense...

Comment: That what I understand. Not easy question ^^

Comment: OK Just to make sure I'm clear... The case where a row will show totals.visits to be 0 and totals.newVisits to be 1 would be a first-time visitor's first event that is a non-interaction event?

Comment: Yes, that's what my data say (except the fact that you will have 'null' instead of 0 in totals.visits)

Answer (score 0):

From definition for `totals.visits`

```
The value is null if there are no interaction events in the session.
```

> Added

Definition for `totals.newVisits`

```
If this is the first visit, this value is 1, otherwise it is null.
```

> how can there be a value for newVisits if there are no interaction events?

I would interpret this as: New User visited page but there was no interaction

See more at [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719)

Comment: But how can there be a value for newVisits if there are no interaction events?

Comment: That just doesn't make sense. New visits are a subset of all visits. 98% of new visits have a corresponding visit count. It's just about 2% of the time that a new visit is registered without any corresponding visit.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't - if to get stuck with just field names. They can be confusing. But if instead to use their description - it might make sense. It is to me. Anyway - `the only what I tried is to point you to fields descriptions vs. just field names` - so if it still doesn't make sense to you - just ignore my answer. Hopefully, someone with google-analytics expertise will provide better answer :o)